# Increment an integer in a JTextField by one

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, increment

I am trying to increment the value of a JTextfield (`tenSecs`) by one for every instance that my other JTextfield (`oneSecs`) reaches 0. I am having difficulty trying to increase the value of my `tenSecs` JTextfield as it is always 0. When manually changing the number, as soon as `oneSecs` reaches 0, `tenSecs` reverts to 0.

```
javax.swing.Timer tm = new javax.swing.Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        AddOneActionPerformed(evt);
    } 
});

private void StartStopTimerActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               

    if (!tm.isRunning()) {
        tm.start();
    } else {
        tm.stop();
    }

    ScheduledExecutorService e= Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(); //Start new scheduled executor service to invoke a timer that start wehn button is pressed
    e.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Follow this Override to do task
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                //Override will let the task run                

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    oneSecsDisplay.setIcon(new ImageIcon("images\\" + TextGrabber() + ".png"));
                    oneSecs.setText( DigitValue.getText());

                    int i = 0;

                    if (Integer.parseInt(oneSecs.getText()) == i) {
                        tenSecs.setText(Integer.toString(i++));
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }, 0, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); //Update will be for every 100 milliseconds concurrent to system time
} 

// Variables declaration - do not modify   
private javax.swing.JTextField oneSecs;
private javax.swing.JTextField tenSecs;
// End of variables declaration
```

I am sure that the error is occurring around the line `int i = 0;`. I am also sure that my way of increasing the value is not the best way to do this, if someone could kindly point me in the correct direction

Comment: Fix your indentation please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, try `tenSecs.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(tenSecs.getText()) + 1));`

Comment: This does work, however my new issue is that the code then adds about 11 instead of one. I think that has something to do with my timer counting updating every 100ms

Comment: No worries, I worked out the issue I was having :) thanks for your help!